# React js - check for element value in array of Options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, so please bear with me. For a onChange function, I need to check if a selected value in a UI is in an array.

```
export const getRestrictedChoices = () => {
    return (<>{RestrictedChoices}</>)
};

const Choices = (
    <>
        // lots of choices
    </>
)

const RestrictedChoices = (
    <>
        //subset of Choices
        <Option value="Choice1">Choice1</Option>
        <Option value="Choice2">Choice2</Option>
        <Option value="Choice3">Choice3</Option>
        <Option value="Choice4">Choice4</Option>
    </>
)
```

I'd like to check if a value selected by user from Choices (dropdown) is in  RestrictedChoices and then update state. I've tried something like this, which results in an error:

```
const onChoiceChange = (value) => {
    if (value && getRestrictedChoices().includes(value)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I also tried in vain to refactor `getRestrictedChoices`, but with similar results:

```
export const getRestrictedChoices = () => {
    return (<>{Choices.values()}</>)
};
```

Both `Choices` and `RestrictedChoices` are in a separate config file.

I'm I approaching the problem in the right way, and if so, what's the best way to test for membership in `RestrictedChoices`?

Comment: Is this a part of a Select/Dropdown?  What is the <Option> component?

Comment: Why would you need to check in options values since the onChange handler will give you the selected option value which means it must exist as the option value?

Comment: if it is, instead of "hardcoded" option, make an array from them, then it would be a simple matter to get the array value.

Comment: Made some edits to make question clearer. So it sounds like the use of `<Option>` tag is specifically for passing to a dropdown or some other Form item and not for such membership tests?

Comment: What is (<>{Choices}</>) ?

Comment: @NenadVracar, missed that edit, should be `(<>{Choices}</>)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I not 100% what your exact need but please see the below example if this helps you:

```
let choices = ["Ivan", "Dragmon", "Guilmon", "Voz Rasposa", "Omar"];
let restrictedChoices = ["Dragmon", "Guilmon"];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { message: "" };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    const newName = e.target.value;
    let msg = "";
    if (restrictedChoices.find((x) => x === newName))
      msg = "Your choice is " + newName;
    else msg = "Your choice is " + newName + ". But it is rectricted.";

    this.setState({ message: msg });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {choices.map((n) => (
            <option key={n} value={n}>
              {n}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**You can run this on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dropdown-example-forked-h9b0j?file=/src/index.js:0-1037)**

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot to see if it gets you on the right track.

```js
let choices = ["Ivan", "Dragmon", "Guilmon", "Voz Rasposa", "Omar"];
let restrictedChoices = ["Dragmon", "Guilmon"];

const isInRestrictedChoices = (value) => restrictedChoices.indexOf(value) > -1; 

console.log(isInRestrictedChoices('Dragmon')) // true
console.log(isInRestrictedChoices('Omar')) // False
```